# Cakephp 3 and MySQL: Importing database triggers when using fixture

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, triggers, phpunit

When using fixtures with cakephp 3 and a MySQL database, I'm importing the tables from the default database into the test database using the `$import` property:

```
class UsersFixture extends TestFixture {
    public $import = ['table' => 'users', 'connection' => 'default'];    
}
```

However it only imports the schema definition but not the related triggers. Is it possible to do so ? Or is it possible to prevent tables to be dropped at the end of the test (and therefor not dropping the triggers) ?